# How can get a mnemonic phrase wallet key (12 words ) from a private key?

Tags: private-key, web3js, ethers.js, web3dart

How can you get a mnemonic phrase wallet key (12 words login key) from a private key?
actually I Will create a mobile app in flutter and a web app in react js
so can you please guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the other way around. Multiple private keys can be derived from the mnemonic phrase, but it's not mathematically possible to derive the phrase from a private key.

See the original BIP39 standard introducing the mnemonic phrase: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki

Comment: So we can not convert the private key to mnemonic-phrase-words with help of web3js , ethers.js  
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: @SachinDivergent That's correct. You can see that the linked tool also converts the mnemonic phrase to private keys - not private key to the phrase.

Comment: Adding some useful command in ethers js to play with wallet :
 - ethers.Wallet.createRandom : create new wallet all with mnemonic and private key
 - ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic : make instance to wallets from mnemonic
in ethers js there is no function to return mnemonic from private key like @PetrHejda said. ps Im a fan of you Petr :))